# input form element is not updating value in Bootstrap Desktop Mobile view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

My issue is when I type something in search and hit the submit button, the Search test box 
still shows old value in DESKTOP. However if I remove the mobile code, then it works perfectly

```
<form >
     <div class="row">
       <!-- Some Bla Bloa HTML for mobile -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 visible-xs">
                 <!-- Some Bla Bloa HTML for mobile -->
                 <input type="text" id="search"  name="search"  value="<?= $search_val ?>" />                     
            </div>
        </div>



     <div class="row"> 
      <!-- Some Bla Bloa HTML for Desktop -->
        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 hidden-xs">
                 <!-- Some Bla Bloa HTML for Desktop -->
                 <input type="text" id="search"  name="search"  value="<?= $search_val ?>" />              
            </div>
        </div>

     </form>
```

Basically the Search button is having different position in mobile and different position in Desktop. So Is there is any way to completely remove in desktop view and vice versa for mobile ?

I have already try display: none method

Comment: Why do you need two inputs you can go with one also for this.Just change the responsive behaviour for this.

Comment: It totally 2 different forms. Diff form in mobile view and diff form in desktop

Comment: Yes, but all the changes can be done by using the same form only  that saves your time.

Comment: I need to have solution in this case only

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the simplest solution, I found is using "Mobile_Detect.php" class

```
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;

if($detect->isMobile()){
    //my mobile form comes here
}{
    //desktop and tablet form comes here
}
```

This has solved the issue